# Find text in Notes app on iPad Pro

Tags: ios, ipad, notes.app

Is it possible to search for text in the Notes app on an iPad Pro?
The closest I have gotten is the search field to the left of the Home screen, but that does not find the fifth occurrence of that text. Is another app better for searching text?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there's no way to search Notes that specifically. It might be a feature that Apple will add in the future, but for now, Spotlight search on iOS will help you can only perform the basic "if note contains this word, display note" searches. There's also no "Find" function within the Notes app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing the "Show More" link above each search group.

For example if I search for the word "Joomla" on my iPad Pro I get this result:

[image: iPad Pro Search Results]

Clicking on the "Show More" to the top right of an Application's result set reveals the rest of the matches, like this:

[image]